# Is there a way to use custom headers when opening WebSocket connection?

Tags: websocket, karate

I'm trying to make a WSS connection using default `karate.webSocket(url, handler)`;
Connection is successful, but desired host requires `Authorization: Bearer XXX` header when upgrading connection from `https` to `wss`
Is it possible to provide custom HTTP headers from `*.feature` file for WebSocket connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually no, we never realized this was needed until now. We've opened an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/775 - hope we can count on you to test this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Sure I'll help with testing (:

Comment: @idontknower would be great if you can build from source and test, it is simple: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide - here is the example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/5dacc7b0616cc30161e77ef098a9017e8ec15be0/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/websocket/echo.feature#L25

Comment: @idontknower and there are some breaking changes in this version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/5dacc7b0616cc30161e77ef098a9017e8ec15be0/README.md#websocket

Comment: Thanks! I've tried, but not sure if i did it correctly (build as in Dev-Guide, set `karate-version` to `1.0.0` in `pom.xml`;
Got this output after `maven test`: https://pastebin.com/DA2ufTz4
Will continue tomorrow

Comment: @idontknower use `null` instead of that `json` !

Comment: (but it guess, i'm doing it wrong again: 
`#karate.webSocket(url, null, null, { Authorization: 'Bearer foo' })` works, but `karate.webSocket(url, null, null, { Authorization: '#(bearerToken)' })` doesn't

Comment: For my last comment about passing variable as a header -- got it working! ```def bearerToken = 'Bearer '+ authToken <...> def socket = karate.webSocket(mdtUrl, null, null, { Authorization: bearerToken } )```

Thanks for implementing headers feature!

Comment: yep ! in this case, it is "pure JS" on the right hand side of the `=`, all good ! there is a section on "Karate Expressions" in the docs that may be worth skimming through once: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

Comment: Sure, I'll dig into it! Thanks for answering my silly questions, and have a nice day! (:

Comment: @idontknower we had to revise the API again, can you see if this look ok: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/README.md#websocket