# Karate WebSocket connection failed due to extension negotiation error

Tags: karate

Got the following exception when connecting to a WebSocket server with `karate.webSocket()`:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: karate.io.netty.handler.codec.CodecException: invalid WebSocket Extension handshake for "permessage-deflate; server_no_context_takeover; client_no_context_takeover"
- com.intuit.karate.http.WebSocketClient.<init>(WebSocketClient.java:144)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.webSocket(ScenarioEngine.java:731)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.webSocket(ScenarioBridge.java:861)
```

The server response has the header

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; server_no_context_takeover; client_no_context_takeover
```

According to the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7692#section-7.1.1.1, a server may include this in the response header.

Tried to specify the same header in the `options` but still failed.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly can be a case we don't support yet. It would be great if you can follow this process and hopefully you can find a public end-point to simulate or try to create a local way - ideally via java / netty or you can use some JS lib etc if that's more convenient.

Instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Of course if you can also provide pointers or a PR, nothing like it. Here is an example of a similar conversation in the past: [Is there a way to use custom headers when opening WebSocket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56131495/143475)