# How to test STOMP protocol based Web sockets in Karate?

Tags: spring, testing, websocket, karate, stomp

I am trying to write Web socket test cases using Karate. In my application the client will be subscribing to various destinations ("/topic/notifs", "/topic/alerts", "/topic/errors") etc.

```
Scenario: text messages
And def socket = karate.webSocket('ws://my websocket url')
When socket.send('hello world!')
And def result = socket.listen(5000)
Then match result == 'hello world!'

When socket.send('another test')
And def result = socket.listen(5000)
Then match result == 'another test'
```

I have tried using the above code snippet. but the result is null..
can you please help me how to subscribe to destination and write test cases for that ?

Comment: I have developed a demo project as the solution for the above query... please find this here https://github.com/sivatejaperam/Karate-websocket-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create any number of websocket instances like this:

```
* def socket1 = karate.webSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org')
* def socket2 = karate.webSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org')
* socket1.send('hello world!')
* socket2.send('another test')

* def result1 = socket1.listen(5000)
* match result1 == 'hello world!'
* def result2 = socket2.listen(5000)
* match result2 == 'another test'
```

So now it is up to you how to manage what to send and when to wait for the `listen()` method to un-block. And please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#websocket

Comment: if the message from server  sent, to a destination like "/topic/alert" does the socket.listen() function catches all the messages that the send through it..?

Comment: @SivaTeja yes if you connected to that url as far as I know

Comment: Thanks for the support @Peter,
We are suing STOMP protocol for websocket communications.. Does Karate support STOMP protocol ?

Comment: @SivaTeja I honestly don't know. I suggest you do some research and help us improve the project if needed, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330249/143475

Comment: I have implemented Web socket client in java and used Karate Async functionality to hook the  Web socket messages to Karate.signal() then I was able to asset the messages 

These are some references that helped me
https://intuit.github.io/karate/#async , 
https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client

below  demo project having JMS integration help me a lot
https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/mock/contract

Comment: @SivaTeja this is great to know. do try to provide feedback or even a PR in case karate's built-in websocket support is lacking. but maybe in your case because it is STOMP - you have done the right thing to write a java adapter. good job !

Comment: Love to raise a PR.that would help many devs like me .. could you please provide guideline on for PR ?

Comment: @SivaTeja https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: Thanks for the you support.. I have implemented the demo project for this and pushed to my repo. ( https://github.com/sivatejaperam/Karate-websocket-demo ) . I would be happy and thankful..if you have some time to look into it and provide feedback... If the demo project has worth raising PR to Karate framework.. please let me know ... i would be very happy to do that... Thanks.

Comment: @SivaTeja thanks. it doesn't identify any gaps in karate's native websocket support, but it certainly can be used as a reference by others who want to do java-interop or stomp support. maybe you can edit your question with a link to your github repo and keep it live