# Karate WebSocket how to listen to multiple messages within one session?

Tags: websocket, integration-testing, karate

For our integration tests we have a scenario where we want to listen to a set amount of messages predefined by the environment we use. I've seen that it's possible to listen to multiple messages by opening up a new connection but that doesn't allow for much flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the docs, because as far as I know, if you define a "handler" function, you can use the same connection for multiple messages and choose when you want to stop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#websocket

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67870765/143475

But if you have a very specific need or custom logic, maybe the best thing is is to write a small piece of Java "glue" code and you will get all the flexibility that you want. You may be able to re-use Karate's Java API such as `com.intuit.karate.http.WebSocketClient` - but this is not documented, and potentially an area where you can research / contribute code.

Here is a good example: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1417023536082812935 of the flexibility that the Java-interop approach provides.

Comment: I've seen the handler function but is it possible to use our own parameters in there without using a literal string.  i.e. something like this?

function(msg, eventId){ return msg.startsWith('{"id":"' + eventId) }

Comment: @ViktorBaert received messages are just plain strings, so the handler function takes a single argument - but you should be able to use `karate.fromString()` if that's what you want: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-fromstring - else maybe you should go down the Java route

Comment: Just want to let you know I'm gonna accept the answer. we went the java-interop route using an okhttp websocket client which fits all our needs, thanks!

Comment: @ViktorBaert thanks for the update ! do consider writing an article or blog post on what you did, I think it would be really useful for others 