# Karate websocket is not sending the "pong" frame when receiving a "ping" frame from server

Tags: websocket, karate

I am using Karate to simulate a longer flow involving a persistent WebSocket connection. The WebSocket connection needs to be kept open for varying durations, ranging from a few seconds to up to 1 hour.

Our WebSocket server employs a mechanism to close the connection if a specific number of "ping" frames sent by the server remain unanswered. Unfortunately, it seems that when Karate connects to a WebSocket, it does not respond to these "ping" frames from the server.

I am currently exploring ways to reproduce this behavior using a script and will update the question with more details shortly.

It's important to note that creating a new WebSocket connection for each operation is not feasible due to the nature of the underlying protocol. The connection must be maintained throughout the entire test duration.

Any insights or suggestions on how to make Karate respond to the server's "ping" frames within the existing WebSocket connection would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried to increase the timeouts for Karate and this did not work.

Comment: in full transparency, the existing websocket implementation is very basic and we are adding better support later as part of the async support which will not be open-source, we started with kafka: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-addons/blob/main/karate-kafka/README.md - so my suggestion is you may need to roll your own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69299321/143475 or reach out to us if you need the websocket support (will be ready in feb 2024)