# Web socket connection fails

Tags: go, karate

Trying to run a test that requires connecting to a web socket.

But I keep getting an error while connecting:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Cannot invoke "org.graalvm.polyglot.SourceSection.getCharacters()" because the return value of "org.graalvm.polyglot.Value.getSourceLocation()" is null
 - com.intuit.karate.graal.JsFunction$Executable.<init>(JsFunction.java:95)
 - com.intuit.karate.graal.JsFunction$Executable.<init>(JsFunction.java:89)
 - com.intuit.karate.graal.JsFunction$Instantiable.<init>(JsFunction.java:132)
 - com.intuit.karate.graal.JsLambda.<init>(JsLambda.java:37)
 - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.webSocket(ScenarioBridge.java:1110)
 - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.webSocket(ScenarioBridge.java:1101)
 - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Sample of the test:

```
Scenario: Account registration and retrieval
    * def handler = function(msg){ return msg.startsWith('{'); }
    * def socket = karate.webSocket('ws://wallet-accountant-karate:8080/ws', handler)

    Given path "http://wallet-accountant-karate:8080/account"
    And request
    """
    {
      bankName: 'a bank',
      name: 'my account',
      accountType: 'checking',
      startingBalance: 123.45,
      startingBalanceDate: '2023-08-26T00:00:00Z',
      currency: 'EUR'
    }
    """
    When method post
    Then status 201
    And match response == {accountId: '#uuid'}
    * listen 1000
    * json result = listenResult
    * match result == { subject: 'account', event: 'accountRegistered' }
```

Any idea on what the issue might be?

Thank you!

Comment: This is my implementation of the web socket https://github.com/mumia/wallet-accountant/blob/main/websocket/modelupdatenotifier.go#L77

Comment: see the first comment under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77801308/143475

Comment: So that means that the demo is wrong?
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/8d4511c40099d8d5f507bc5292f38734dcf26bfb/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/websocket.feature#L5

Comment: the demo is for a simple case, I really can't say if it will work for all kinds of websocket servers. some teams use it just fine. by the way karate is open source, anyone is welcome to contribute